# "Contribution Detail Report" issues in CiviCRM 5.8.1

Tags: civireport

The "Contribution Detail Report" template is not fetching the soft credits related data correctly in CiviCRM version 5.8.1. It is showing "Contribution" for all rows, even for  Soft credits and the "Soft credit type" column is not showing any data. Kindly help me to fix the issue.

Thank you

[image: Please find the screenshot]

Comment: Make sure you have enabled `Contribution OR Soft Credit?` to required value in `Filters` tab of the report. If it is selected as `Contributions Only` - no soft credit rows will be listed

Comment: @jitendra-fuzion Thanks for the reply. I had set the the "Contribution OR Soft Credit?" to "Soft Credits only" and the issue is still there.

Comment: UPDATE: @jitendra-fuzion The report is working correctly with the whole "Report" directory of CiviCRM version 4.7 placed in a custom-php folder, but not with 5.8.1 verison.